# SonarQube doesn't show any results

Tags: spring-boot, maven, sonarqube

I don't know why sonarqube isn't showing any resuls while running `sonar-scanner` and even `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar` and everything is successfully but with no results.

**this is my configuration:**

> sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
> sonar.projectKey=releveproject
> sonar.projectName=releveproject
> sonar.java.binaries=**/**target/classes
> sonar.login=admin
> sonar.password=1234

**POM.xml**

```
<plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ini</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <property environment="env" />
                                    <echoproperties prefix="env." />
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <jacoco-agent.destfile>**/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sonar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```

**This is how it looks like on sonarqube dashboard:**

[image]

Comment: Looks like do miss a slash in sonar.java.binaries before target.

Comment: I added the slash but same result

Comment: Please execute the command `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -X` in verbose mode to see the error.

Comment: Also, try to include this in your sonar.properties `sonar.inclusions=.`